# ionic, Facebook4 Cordova blank screen crashing

Tags: facebook, ionic-framework, cordova-facebook

I am using facebook4 cordova plugin to authenticate my users to firebase. I tested on many devices. In most of them, it is working properly but in some of them I am getting blank screens( I guess its crashing). I think it is from the android version. Some of the crashed devices were **Android 4.3 and 4.4.2.**

I ran this command: **ionic run android --livereload --consolelogs**

and got this:

> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 3.94 secs
>
> ```
> file:/C:/Users/Paul/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.pom
>          file:/C:/Users/Paul/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/23.4.0/support-v4-23.4.0.jar
>      Required by:
>          :android:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.1
>    > Could not find com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0.
>      Searched in the following locations:
>          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.4.0/cardview-v7-23.4.0.pom
>          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.4.0/cardview-v7-23.4.0.jar
>          file:/C:/Users/Paul/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.4.0/cardview-v7-23.4.0.pom
>          file:/C:/Users/Paul/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.4.0/cardview-v7-23.4.0.jar
>          file:/C:/Users/Paul/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.4.0/cardview-v7-23.4.0.pom
>          file:/C:/Users/Paul/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/cardview-v7/23.4.0/cardview-v7-23.4.0.jar
>      Required by:
>          :android:unspecified > com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.14.1
> ```

What could be the main cause of this?